# Is there an example for using dynamic modules on the Play Store when the dynamic module is used by a library module and not from the main app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, android-module

I've looked over Google's examples and codelabs and they look pretty simple but they are for modules that the main app access directly. My problem is that I have a module that the main app never access directly.

Basically I have this:

App -> Module A -> Module B -> Module C

So `App` imports `A` as a gradle `implementation`, `A` imports `B` and `B` imports `C`.

I want `C`, that is rarely used and large, to be a dynamic module.

I've already set `C` to be `apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'` but I'm getting stuck on the dependencies.

If I set `dynamicFeatures = [':C']` inside the gradle file of `B`, it fails because `Could not set unknown property 'dynamicFeatures' for object`

If I set the `dynamycFeatures` plus the `implement` line on `App` I get `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :C`

So how do I do this with this project hierarchy?

Thanks.

Comment: If "prodDebug" is a build type you have in the main module, make sure that you have that build type in all your modules. See if that solves the build issue. I had the same issue.

Comment: Any luck in getting the code built?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked plaid? https://github.com/android/plaid

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-patchwork-plaid-monolith-to-modularized-app-60235d9f212e
They solved your problem using Reflection API

Answer (score 0):

If "prodDebug" is a build type you have in the main module, make sure that you have that build type in all your modules. See if that solves the build issue. I had the same issue.

And In-General, you would have an app hierarchy where you would have one base module and the dynamic modules that you can plug-in into the base module. This has worked quiet successfully.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help, but maybe my setup is just too old since it predates android studio. I tried setting up a dynamic module and letting android studio do it and that still failed.